# x509 nullpointerexception in Android app while debugging in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I had been making steady progress debugging an app when all of a sudden I started getting a null pointer exception when contacting the server to login. The problem does not occur if I run the app  standalone on the device. The stacktrace follows. There seem to be some indications this is a problem with Eclipse but I'm baffled as to why it started happening all of a sudden. Others are contacting this server successfully. I've tried reverting to codebase from before the problem. I've rebooted my machine, my device. Tried Eclipse 3.7 and 3.8. Nothing seems to work. Short of spinning up on IntelliJ is there anything I can try on Eclipse?

I see this problem on a LG Revolution 2.3.4. No issues on a Droid 2.2 or HDMaxx 4.0.4

```
Thread [<11> pool-2-thread-1] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
Class.forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader) line: 234   
Class.forName(String) line: 181 
X509Certificate.<clinit>() line: 60 
OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper(OpenSSLSocketImpl).verifyCertificateChain(byte[][], String) line: 658  
NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(int, FileDescriptor, NativeCrypto$SSLHandshakeCallbacks, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]    
OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper(OpenSSLSocketImpl).startHandshake(boolean) line: 474   
OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper(OpenSSLSocketImpl).startHandshake() line: 328  
HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(SSLSocketFactory, boolean) line: 185   
HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(boolean) line: 433 
HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection() line: 378   
HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl).connect() line: 205   
HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl).getOutputStream() line: 614   
HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream() line: 268  
LoginRequest.performNetworkCall() line: 52  
LoginRequest(RevelationRequest).loadDataFromNetwork() line: 28  
LoginRequest(RevelationRequest).loadDataFromNetwork() line: 1   
CachedSpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork() line: 28   
RequestProcessor.processRequest(CachedSpiceRequest) line: 247   
RequestProcessor$2.run() line: 172  
Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() line: 444  
FutureTask$Sync.innerRun() line: 306    
FutureTask.run() line: 138  
ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1088  
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 581   
Thread.run() line: 1019
```

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with the debugger not handling a custom hostname verifier for SSL certificates - I had to debug using android.util.Log statements running in normal mode.

Comment: Thanks Drake. I hope I don't have to resort to that!! Further info: the problem is happening on a LG Revolution 2.3.4. No issues on a Droid 2.2 or HDMaxx 4.0.4.